In a reference, how to show the object name as part of the link?
Please consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{section1}
foo
\section{Second}
Here we link to \cref{section1} before explaining further.
\end{document}

The reference works as expected, but does not look as desired. In a PDF viewer, the digit 1 is rendered as a link; when I click on it, the viewer moves the first section title to the top of the page.
So I'm nearly there, but I really would like not only the digit 1 to be rendered as link, but the whole reference including the object name. In other words, I would like to have the whole string section 1 rendered as link.
How can I achieve that?

The long story:
Actually, I already have worked out a solution to that problem myself. The following code fragment shows the definition and usage of two new commands that (at the first sight) do what I want:
%...
%Definition
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{\hypertarget{#1}{#2}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\cref*{#1}}}
%...
%Usage
\mylabel{dhm}{\section{About destruction of human rights}}
Here we refer to \myref{dhm} and go on.
%...


However, I had to abandon these commands and their working principle because they are obviously not compatible with the caption and hypcap packages.
I need one of the latter for the same reasons as in this post. The solution shown in the accepted answer to that post works for me, but not for images that I am referencing using the new commands I have created. In other words, caption and hypcap generally work as expected, but don't effect anything with references that are created by my new commands.
Can somebody help me out of this?

The namelink option will include the name in the link:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{First}\label{section1}
foo
\section{Second}
Here we link to \cref{section1} before explaining further.
\end{document}



That is definitely a new speed record. Thank you so much, accepted and +1 of course. I am embarrassed now, because yesterday I have studied cleveref's PDF documentation, but obviously have missed the nameinlink option.

@Binarus You are welcome! There are many options, easy to miss one :)
